# JavaScript method to import a local JSON file every x amount of minutes

Tags: javascript, json

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I've been hunting around for a solution for this problem:

I have names and numbers being written to a data.json file in the same directory as my JavaScript file.  What I'm looking for is every few minutes to check that data.json and update my HTML p tag with the changes.

My HTML block looks like this:

```
...
<body>
  <p id="mydata">
  </p>
</body>
...
```

My data.json looks like this:

```
[{"Name":"Charlie","Number":"5"},{"Name":"Patrick","Number":"3"}]
```

My Javascript block looks like this:

```
...
setInterval(function(){
    var json = // read in json file
    //this is the part I'm missing
    document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML = json;
},300000); // every 5 minutes
```

Comment: Is it a local file ..?

Comment: It is a local file

Comment: then following answer with upvote is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.getJSON will load local json file

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON("yourjsonfile.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json); 
        document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML = json;
    });
},300000); // every 5 minutes
```

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: you should define jquery by importing it in your html

Comment: add <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to your html header

Answer (score 0):

Make sure about 2 things:

1. You are **Stringifying** JSON object
2. You are **dont have the same values** every time you reading from the file

Your method actually works, you can check it using a simple counter for example:

```js
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function(){
counter++;
    var json = JSON.stringify([{"Name":"Charlie","Number":"5"},{"Name":"Patrick","Number":"3"}]);
    document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML = counter + json;
},1000);
```

```html
<p id="mydata">
</p>
```

Comment: The only problem with this is my local json file will be changed about every 15 seconds, so It will not be static.